# Is it Bad Practice to Observe a Value That You Know Wont Change?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an iOS app that is using Firebase on the back end. I am trying to get a better understanding of the Firebase's `observe` & `observeSingleEvent` functions. Simply put, I was wondering if i should create two separate closures (`observe`/`observeSingleEvent`) depending on the data that is to be observed.

For instance, I have a label, "LabelA" that is very likely to change (number of likes, follower count, etc) which I would place in the `observe` function. I also have a label, "label B" that isn't going to change, but still has to be fetched from Firebase.

Would it be okay for me to place the logic for "label B" in the `observe` function used for "label A", or it would it be best for me to place "label B" in a `observeSingleEvent` closure of its own?

EDIT:

```
Database.database().reference(withPath: "users").child(path_to_some_user).observe(.value) {
    ... //Observe Total Likes value & update UI when it changes
    ... //Is it bad practice to set up "Label B" here?
}

Database.database().reference(withPath: "users").child(path_to_some_user).observeSingleEvent(.value) {
    ... //Or should i setup "label B" here in its own closure
}
```

JSON structure is as follows

- Users

  - Some User

    - Total Likes Count <- is expected/likely to change in real-time (i.e value to be used for "label A")
    - Username <- is highly unlikely to change, don't care about updating with real-time data (i.e value to be used for "label B")

Comment: "place the logic for "label B" in the observe function used for "label A" Can you show the code for what this would look like? It'd also help to see the JSON structure you have in mind.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was closed so voting to re-open.

Comment: .observe and .observeSingleEvent are for two different purposes. `.observe` is used  if you want to be notified of changed data. `.observeSingleEvent` is getting data once and you're not interested in future changes. An example. Suppose a chat app has two types of users; user and admin. User types don't change. When a user logs in, the app reads their node to determine their user type; `.observeSingleEvent` is useful here as the data needs to be read once and not again. However, when the user posts a message for others to see, other users need to be notified so `.observe` is useful here.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! One more thing i'd like to touch on - is it best to create one of each (.observe & .observeSingleEvent) if you have data that you want to observe and have data that only needs to be fetched once? Or is it better to place all of it in a single .observe block? i.e. Is there harm in observing a value that isn't expected to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.observe and .observeSingleEvent are for two different purposes.

```
.observe is used when you want to be notified of changed data.

.observeSingleEvent gets data **once** and you're not notified about future changes
```

An example.

Suppose a chat app has two types of users; user and admin. For this example, user types don't change.

When a user logs in, the app reads that users node to determine their user type:

```
/users/uid_x
```

and the node structure would be this

```
uid_x
  user_name: "Henry"
  user_type: "Admin"
  fav_food: "Pizza"
```

.observeSingleEvent is useful here as the data needs to be read once and not again.

However, when the user posts a message for others to see, other users need to be notified so .observe is useful for that purpose.

Keep in mind that adding .observe to a node will read in all the child nodes once, and then leave an observer to notify the app of future changes. You can get more fine-grained detail by using .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved instead of .value.